# Magento 2 recently view product widget image related issue

Tags: magento2, widget

I am using the latest version of Magento and recently added a 'Recently Viewed' widget to the homepage. A few days ago, we didn't have actual product images on our server, so we were using third-party image URLs to display them. There was no code in place for displaying product images in the 'Recently Viewed' widget.

Since then, we have uploaded the images directly into Magento, but the widget still only shows images from the third-party URLs. Everywhere else in the store, the images are being displayed from Magento correctly.

Does anyone have an idea about how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.